# I have this table and I want to replace empty value with last non empty value in bigquery how can I it?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnR7R.png      thi

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an array type, not empty.

[image]

You can [flatten an existing table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) with an [Array type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array_type) by joining the unnest operation result.

```
SELECT int_value, flatten_array_sample
FROM (
  SELECT 
      1 AS int_value, [1,2,3] AS array_sample
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
      2 AS int_value, [3,5,7] AS array_sample
), UNNEST(array_sample) as flatten_array_sample
```

[image]